# How do I fix JMeterPluginsCMD "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" error

Tags: jmeter, window, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to use the JMeterPluginsCMD on Windows to generate load test result graphs after a JMeter run. I installed the plugin from the JMeter Plugins Manager.

When I run a command, I get an error message. What can I do about this error message?

```
`JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png "test.png" --input-jtl "...\test-3.jtl" --plugin-type ResponseTimesOverTime --width 800 --height 600`
```

The plugin JMeterPluginsCMD.bat existed in `JMETER_home/bin`

[image]

I am getting the following error:

```
2021-11-17 09:54:35,131 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'Cannot invoke "java.util.Properties.getProperty(String, String)" because "org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.appProperties" is null' occurred when fetching String property:'sampleresult.default.encoding', defaulting to: ISO-8859-1
2021-11-17 09:54:35,137 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Exception 'Cannot invoke "java.util.Properties.getProperty(String)" because "org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.appProperties" is null' occurred when fetching String property:'jmeterPlugin.prefixPlugins'
2021-11-17 09:54:35,138 INFO k.a.j.PluginsCMDWorker: Using JMeterPluginsCMD v. N/A
2021-11-17 09:54:35,139 INFO o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US
2021-11-17 09:54:35,147 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading user properties from: E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\user.properties
2021-11-17 09:54:35,148 INFO k.a.j.JMeterPluginsUtils: Loading system properties from: E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin\system.properties
ERROR: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: E:\Outcode\ProtocolNow\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:990)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:593)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:515)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:484)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:430)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:383)
        at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper.<init>(SaveService.java:82)
        at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService$XStreamWrapper.<init>(SaveService.java:80)
        at org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService.<clinit>(SaveService.java:113)
        at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.processSamples(CSVSaveService.java:144)
        at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.loadExistingFile(ResultCollector.java:380)
        at kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker.doJob(PluginsCMDWorker.java:138)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.ReporterTool.processParams(ReporterTool.java:255)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:62)
        at kg.apc.cmdtools.PluginsCMD.processParams(PluginsCMD.java:21)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at kg.apc.cmd.UniversalRunner.main(UniversalRunner.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @75c072cb
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields.locate(Fields.java:40)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit>(TreeMapConverter.java:50)
        ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The right place to seek for help with this regards is [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins)

Coming back to your question:

In the `JMeterPluginsCMD.bat` change this line:

```
java -jar %~dp0\..\lib\cmdrunner-2.2.jar  --tool Reporter %*
```

to this one:

```
java --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -jar %~dp0\..\lib\cmdrunner-2.2.jar  --tool Reporter %*
```

---

Be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.4.1 (or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.